# How can i convert string to byte array in C# with special characters like é, á?

Tags: c#, csv, encoding

My problem is that when I want to convert a string to a byte array the special letter conversion fails.

Like:

- In string: `Városmajor`
- In byte array: `Vï¿½rosmajor`

My code aims to create a string from a data table and then send as a response CSV file.

```
public ActionResult DownloadCSV(int id)
{
    string res = provider.GetCSVtoDownload(id);
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(q);
    this.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment;data.csv");
    this.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
    return File(buffer, "text/csv", "orderdata.csv");
}

public string GetCSVtoDownload(int id)
{
   var data = ctx.myDbSet.Find(id);
   var dt = new DataTable();

   dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
   dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));

   object[] o = {
       data.id,
       data.name,
   };

   dt.Rows.Add(o);

   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   IEnumerable<string> columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                     Select(column => column.ColumnName);
   sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

   foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
   {
       IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString());
       sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
   }

   return sb.ToString();
}
```

I already tried: UTF8 and ASCII encoding.

Comment: Try using another encoding like UTF-8?

Comment: Yes i already tried

Comment: Question: what bytes do you think should be the output? Different encodings / code-pages have different byte sequences, so: the choice is key. There is no "right" answer other than "the one you expect". So: what byte sequence do you expect for `é` and `á`, **expressed as hex**? For example, UTF-8 would say C3 A9 and C3 A1 respectively

Comment: Did you try Unicode?

Comment: @useruser wait... You mean in bytearray? I think that this may be an expected behavior under a bytearray? And what you need to do is to decode this bytearray? (I don't know whether it is correct)

Comment: Which program did you use to view the file once downloaded? If the string is UTF-8 and that program doesn't support that it can appear as you describe.

Comment: @fredrik: MS excel

Comment: And did you tell excel to use the same encoding as the file is exported with? You might also need to write a http header that specifies the encoding - I don't see one in your code now.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like this is fundamentally an encoding problem.

The reality is that we (programmers) have lied to regular users for decades, and made them think that there is such a thing as a "text file". This is simply not true; or it is a gross over-simplification. A "text file" just means a binary file (all data is binary, really) that happens to be encoded with a text encoding, which is to say: if you know the right encoding, you can run the binary through the encoding and get the right text back.

The problem is: **there are lots of encodings**, and for basic alpha-numeric characters in the non-international English range, a lot of them **are completely interchangeable** - all code-pages and UTF-8 all agree on the first 128 code-points. But... then it gets messy, and `é` and `á` are outside of that range.

There is no "right" or "wrong" way here to encode such characters - the only relevant answer is "make sure both ends agree", which might mean using some advanced load option in the tool to pick the encoding. If in doubt, UTF-8 should almost always be your default choice. And for extra luck, you could try including the UTF-8 "BOM" at the start of the file (`new UTF8Encoding(true)` may work, the "BOM" is also called "preamble"). Alternatively, just make sure that the file starts with the bytes xEF,0xBB,0xBF (which is the UTF-8 "BOM"). The "BOM" is recognized by many tools to help them understand which encoding to use, so since you mention Excel, it is *possible* that Excel will recognize the "BOM" and understand that this is UTF-8, and make everything work correctly.